# How to save an email's attachment to a specific folder?

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I searched the web and wrote the below code.

Getting

> Run-time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)': Automation Error

VBA Code:

```vb
Sub SaveWklyReports()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim p As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.Folders(1).Folders("Test")

For Each p In fol.Items
    
    If p.Class = olMail Then
        Set mi = p
        Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime
    End If

Next p

End Sub
```

Comment: What line of code throws the error? Which property exactly gives the error message?

Comment: For starters, never hardcode folder index (`ns.Folders(1)`). Secondly, do you get that error immediately or only after processing a few messages?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes I got the error immediately

Comment: You are assuming you can only have MailItem objects in the folder. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

That error means there is no such folder as `ns.Folders(1).Folders("Test")`

Instead of using the explicit index `1` use the correct folder name e.g.

```
Set fol = ns.Folders(myFolderName).Folders("Test")
```

In my case `myFolderName` is set to my email address for my main account or to the name of the shared mail account for others - for you it will depend on what you are trying to access

Comment: If I use Set fol = ns.Folders(myFolderName).Folders("Test"), getting Runtime Error 440

Comment: @MuraliKrishnaSannapareddy - have you set `myFolderName` to the name of a folder in your instance of Outlook? If so, Is there a folder called "Test" immediately below that folder? 440 usually occurs when the "thing" does not have the property or method you are trying to use - in this case it could be that ns.Folders(myFolderName) does not have any folders OR myFolderName is not a sub-folder of the Namespace "MAPI"